# Redirect page to dynamic URL Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm a beginner on using django platform to create a mini project website and use a function based view. One of the feature in my project is a profile page that allowing user to edit the personal information. Here is my user profile **models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
company_url = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
country = CountryField(null=True)

AFF_CHOICES = (('Academic','Academic'),
                ('Business','Business'),
                ('Non-profit','Non-profit'),
                ('Industry/Government','Industry/Government'))

affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=AFF_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_picture', null=True, default='profile_picture/defaultphoto.png')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

Here is my **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'dashboard'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('<int:pk>/profile/',profile,  name='profile'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit_profile/',edit_profile,  name='edit_profile'),
```

as you can see it will pass user PK so it will look like this (example on profile page) http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/42/profile/ and it's already works. Here is my profile and edit_profile **views.py**:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/profile.html')

def edit_profile(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user,)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been updated.')
            return redirect('/profile/dashboard/') #The problem is here #Still static

    else :
        form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'editform':form}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/editprofile.html', context)
```

i've tried this case with static url (not passing the user PK on url) and it is already works. How do i pass the user PK correctly after user edited their profile. (I want to redirect them to /dashboard/user:pk/profile). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
return redirect('dashboard:profile', pk=pk)
```

Comment: tried this and it's raised an error : NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/42/edit_profile/ -  Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'user': 42}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/profile/$']  any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide profile view? try this:return redirect('dashboard: profile', pk=pk)

Comment: Ok i've added the profile views, i only render some profile.html page on it. should i write some codes??

Comment: did you try this?return redirect('dashboard:profile', pk=pk)

Comment: yes but it still get the exact error. any suggestion how to pass the url in the submit button of that form to get the PK? `{% url 'dashboard:profile' request.user.pk %}` is this already right?

Comment: yes the pk is already correct on that page (seen in the url), but after i click the submit button and expect a redirect to the profile page, the errors occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

# In your view
return redirect(reverse('dashboard:profile', kwargs={'id': pk}))
```

Comment: tried this and it's raised an error : `NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/42/edit_profile/ -  Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'id': 42}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/profile/$'] ` any suggestions?